# Checkbox to be checked on having value Y

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a checkbox bound to a viewmodel's observable property, whose value will be Y or N. I want the the checkbox to be checked when the value is Y and unchecked when the value is N. How to achieve this?

I am able to achieve it if the value is 0 or 1 but not on Y and N. What will be the way to achieve the desired behavior on having value Y or N?

The check-box code is as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: job.Open" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [computed writable observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html):

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.actualObservable = ko.observable('Y');
  self.relatedObservable = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return self.actualObservable() === 'Y'; },
    write: function(x) { self.actualObservable(!!x ? 'Y' : 'N'); }
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: relatedObservable"> = Checked<br />
<i data-bind="text: actualObservable"></i> = Actual
```

You could also just bind the `actualObservable` to the checkbox, and make the computed observable read only. IMHO that would usually make more sense, but it depends on your context. That version looks like this:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.actualObservable = ko.observable(true);
  self.relatedObservable = ko.computed(function() { 
    return !!self.actualObservable() ? 'Y' : 'N'; 
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: actualObservable"> = Checked<br />
<i data-bind="text: relatedObservable"></i> = Actual
```